# ExecuteNonQuery :: Error Data too long for column at row 2 whether i have insert .csv file into Mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, csv, insert, mysql-workbench

ExecuteNonQuery :: Error Data too long for column at row 2 whether i have insert .csv file into Mysql using c#.

In table put all datatypes varchar(500) CHARACTER but still i am getting issue.

Comment: Please check value of csv file that value of  any field is more than 500 character or not.

Comment: Thank you... No there is no filed more than 500 char, and records are insert up to 70 rows after that getting above issue.

Comment: Check any miss match with fields with your CSV. Check carefully insert command.